# Error Handling for ASP.NET MVC Application does not display error page correclty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, stack-trace

My production server does not allow to display error details (as i guess since setting custom errors off did not help).
So I tried to use built in error handling feature of application.
I have below codes:
This is inside `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    //Server.ClearError();
    //Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    var currentController = " ";
    var currentAction = " ";
    var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null &&
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null &&
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    var controller = new HomeController();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var action = "Error";
    var statusCode = 500;
    if (ex is ArgumentException)
    {
        action = "NotFound";
        statusCode = 404;
    }
    httpContext.ClearError();
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
    httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = action;
    controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
    ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
}
```

This is my `Error.cshtml` which reside in `Views\Shared\Error.cshtml`:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1 class="error">Error.</h1>
    <h2 class="error">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <h4>@Model.Exception.Message</h4>
        <h5>@Model.Exception.StackTrace</h5>
    }
    else
    {
        <h1> error</h1>
    }
</hgroup>
```

And here is parts of  my web.config:
  
    
    
    ....

When I call my site at [http://exmaple.com](http://emenu.ir) it will redirect to address [http://exmaple.com/Error.cshtml?aspxerrorpath=/](http://emenu.ir/Error.cshtml?aspxerrorpath=/)  and auto-refresh infintely.
In my debug environment, when error happens Error page is rendered normally and display exception trace.

I want to know how can I find the root cause of this error or how can I see error trace?

Comment: Wild guess - maybe your error page is itself throwing an error and cause the infinity loop. Try putting some properties in your `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` model that compute displayed exception information and put everything in `try.. catch` blocks so that no exception can be generated.

Comment: @Alexei I did  tried to comment any codes however here is what server support screenshot tells me even after this change:`“An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page…”`

Comment: Can you check if the following code palce in `global.asax.cs` returns an error?: `protected void Application_Error()
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            // log somewhere the error for later check
        }`. You can also check Event Viewer, as unhandled IIS exceptions are shown there as warnings.